# ipython notebook not launching

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I cannot get ipython notebook to launch. I used the command "ipython notebook" in command prompt but I got an error saying that "ipython" is not recognized as a command. I have Python 3.3 and ipython 1.2.1. This command works on my other Windows machine and I used the same process to install ipython. The only difference is that I am using Python 2.7 on my other Windows machine. I feel like there is a really simple fix or I have made a silly error. Any ideas?

**Edit:**
I tried ThomasK's suggestion in the comments below and received the following error displayed in the image below.

[image: Ipython notebook error on call]

Comment: Try `ipython3 notebook`. Or upgrade to IPython 2.0, which installs both `ipython` and `ipython3` on Python 3.

Comment: I tried ipython3 notebook and I tried upgrading to Iptyhon 2.0. Still no luck.

Comment: IPython may not be on your `%PATH%`. Can you do `py -m IPython`?

Comment: That command works just fine in command prompt -- it starts up ipython in the command prompt shell.

Comment: OK, you should be able to run `py -m IPython notebook` to start the notebook.

Comment: I believe I tried that immediately after I tested the command in your previous message. I will try it again but unfortunately I left my laptop at work so I will not be able to do so until Monday. Please be patient with me and I will reply again once I try the command.

Comment: @ThomasK I tried the command and received an error with a long traceback. I modified my question with an image to display the traceback.

Comment: Looks like you don't have pyzmq installed. You can install it with pip or an [exe installer](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyzmq). But there will probably be other things you don't have set up. We recommend downloading something like [Anaconda](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/), which includes all the necessary packages. If you want to use Python 3, you could try [Pyzo](http://www.pyzo.org/downloads.html), which is similar.

Comment: Thank you for your help @ThomasK. The information you have given me above is sufficient enough to describe why I am having this problem and possible solutions. You can post that as an answer if you like. I think I will try Pyzo. I have used Anaconda in the past but there was something I did not like about it (though I don't remember what it is) and have avoided using it since.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reposting as an answer:

Looks like you don't have pyzmq installed. You can install it with pip or an exe installer. But there will probably be other things you don't have set up. We recommend downloading something like Anaconda, which includes all the necessary packages. If you want to use Python 3, you could try Pyzo, which is similar.

Answer (score 1):

As of writing, it's normal to get these messages. It just means you are missing some python packages. I suggest installing them as follows: `pip install --user [package]`. The other ones it might complain about are listed [here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/install/install.html):

```
jinja2, needed for the notebook
sphinx, needed for nbconvert
pyzmq, needed for IPython’s parallel computing features, qt console and notebook
pygments, used by nbconvert and the Qt console for syntax highlighting
tornado, needed by the web-based notebook
nose, used by the test suite
```