# Open IPython Notebook 2.7 and 3.4 in Parallel

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ipython

I've searched through SO, but haven't found a clear answer to what I'm trying to do.  If the answer already exists, I'd appreciate a pass-along of the URL.  For reference: I'm new to running multiple Python versions, and can run code through both interpreters.  I'm on Windows 7, and used the anaconda distribution.

In my `cmd`, I've activated Python2.7 as default.  To access Python2.7 and Python3.4, I use `python` and `py -3` respectively.  I'd like to be able to open IPython browser notebooks for 2.7 and 3.4 in parallel, but am not sure how the command would look/how to determine which browser window is using which interpreter.

From @Jonas Buckner's comment on [How to activate Ipython Notebook and QT Console with Python 3.4 in Anaconda 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23983822/how-to-activate-ipython-notebook-and-qt-console-with-python-3-4-in-anaconda-2-0), it seems that I can specify the port.  My question is, how do I know which port # is associated with each version?  Is this fixed, or is there some way I can determine which port?

[ipython notebook not launching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23273164/ipython-notebook-not-launching) mentions `ipython` vs `ipython3`, which I would really prefer, to the port method.  However, when I try `ipython3 notebook`, I get:

```
'ipython3' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.
```

Is it possible to set up an alias?  If so, how?

To reiterate from above, once I've opened notebooks in parallel, is there a way for me to tell which notebook is which version?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how did you install ipython?

Comment: Used the anaconda distribution.  I normally use 3.4, but had to install 2.7 for a project.

Comment: have you tried installing ipython for python3 using pip?

Comment: No.  Why do you ask? I already have ipython 2.2.  Do you think the set-up configuration would be different?

Comment: I have very little windows experience but I presumed you would get different commands for 2 and 3, the latest is also 2.3.1, You could also try installing from here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#ipython

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *specify* the port, so *you* choose the port number to use for each version; there are no predefined ports for python2 vs python3.

For example:

```
ipython notebook --port=10000
```

will run IPython, using the default python interpreter, on port `10000`. You can then connect to that notebook by going to `http://localhost:10000/tree`.

Say that `ipython2` launches IPython with python2.7 while `ipython3` launches IPython with python3.4 you can run both IPythons with the commands:

```
ipython2 notebook --port=27272
ipython3 notebook --port=34343
```

If the URL of a page starts with `localhost:27272` then the notebook is running python 2.7 while if the URL starts with `localhost:34343` then the notebook is running python 3.4.

---

Note that this, by itself, has *nothing* to do with different python versions.
You can run two IPython instances on different ports using the same interpreter.

If you want to launch IPython with a specific interpreter you can launch it as a module using the `-m` switch:

```
python2.7 -m IPython notebook --port=27272
python3.4 -m IPython notebook --port=34343
```

so you don't need to have `ipython` or `ipython3` as recognized commands. You simply need to be able to run the two different interpreters.

Again: to understand which version of the interpreter you are using you can simply look at the port number in the URL. Or you can check `sys.version_info` in the interpreter.

---

If you have to do this often you may be interested in putting the port number setting in a configuration file. I don't know whether it's possible to have two different configuration files, one for python2 and one for python3. However, inside the file, you can check the version and set the right port number.

Comment: the OP has stated that ipython3 is not recognised

Comment: @PadraicCunningham That's why below I told him that he can use `python3.4 -m IPython` instead. He may create an alias `alias ipython3=python3.4 -m IPython`.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the port in `ipython_notebook_config.py` file, which is normally located in the `~/.ipython/profile_nbserver` directory

For example, in my profile I have set it to run on port 9999

```
# Configuration file for ipython-notebook.
c = get_config()
c.NotebookApp.port = 9999
```

You can get `Python` version with the following command:

```
import sys
print (sys.version)
```